# Why didn't Goku think of using Instant Transmission to get out of Hell before trying what Android 17 did?

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

Android 17 got out by opening the gap between Hell and earth. But instead of doing the same, Goku could have used Instant Transmission to get out. Why didn't he do so? Is it because of the fact that he was turned into a child and he could use Instant Transmission only as a Super Saiyan 4 (taking into consideration that Goku could only be a Super Saiyan 4 for a certain amount of time)?

Comment: While some minor copy-editing has been done, I still have no clue what is being asked here. Please edit your question to use clear, standard English  (at least as best you can).

Comment: I believe that you are correct in thinking that the reason he didn't use Instant Transmission was that he could only use it as a Super Saiyan 4.

Comment: The answer could lie in the way instant transmission could work, the user doesn't just "disappear" and "appear" rather they move at a super fast speed to where they want to be, so if they are in a contained space (like hell) they cannot just "warp" out. (note, this is based on opinion, and I really do not watch DB)

Comment: @Denslat and you're wrong. (Why even make such a statement if you don't watch it?) -- it has been discussed time and time again that instant transmission being superspeed was a bad translation. It has been stated that instant transmission is exactly what it is: Instant. This is also why Goku can travel to the other realm (King Kai's planet is in a similar realm as hell is! Note that if you fall off snake-way you get to the gates of hell!). So your comment is simply wrong. Goku could IT out of hell. He could IT anywhere.

Comment: Hell can be considered another dimension and you can't go between dimensions as usual. Like King Yama said, once you get there, you can't come back

Answer (score 0):

From the [Instant Transmission article](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Instant_Transmission) on Dragon Ball Wiki:

> When Goku became a child in Dragon Ball GT, the ability to use this technique was greatly hindered to the point where he just randomly travels to places a short distance away; however, as a Super Saiyan 4, he is able to use the ability to its full potential. When he is given energy by Goten, Trunks, and Gohan during the battle against Syn Shenron, kid Goku is able to properly use Instant Transmission.